# wxPython, how to get widget's size in millimeter?

Tags: wxpython

Suppose I have a `Paper (wx.Panel)` and I want to draw a chart on it in millimeter scale, so I set the mapping mode of the `PaintDc` to millimeter: `dc.SetMapMode(wx.MM_METRIC)` and then I am going to draw the horizontal axis.

```
class Paper(wx.Panel):
    def onPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetMapMode(wx.MM_METRIC)
        w, h = self.GetClientSize() <<< This line get size in pixel.
        dc.DrawLine(0, h-10, w-1, h-10)
```

I want the axis to stay 10 millimeters afar from the bottom of the paper, so I query the paper's size as `w, h = self.GetClientSize()`, but the problem is the size is in pixel rather than millimeter.

**What is the function to get panel's size in mm., or is there a function to map size in pixel to mm.?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a python programmer, nor used wxWidgets for more than small times, so my answer is purely assuming that no method will do this for you.

You need to get the resolution of the screen (normally 75dpi), and then calculate how many mm a pixel will equal on that screen.

Details of screen resolution http://www.scantips.com/basics1a.html

Don't assume that without calibration or getting the monitor info from some source, you will get a rule and measure the same mm as your draw.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, I have found that there are functions to get the screen's size in pixel and in mm.: `wx.GetDisplaySize()` and `wx.GetDisplaySizeMM()`, which I can use to calculate the amount of millimeters per pixel `mmperpx`, which in turn can used to convert size in pixels to millimeters.

```
def px2mm(pixels):
    px = float(wx.GetDisplaySize()[1])
    mm = float(wx.GetDisplaySizeMM()[1])
    mmperpx = mm/px
    return mmperpx * pixels
```

Comment: So, can you mark my response as an answer, I think you are doing what I'm said. Except from the fact it can do wrong results depending on the monitor, so if you need precision results thats not the best way.

Citations from where http://markmail.org/message/2prubyh6h5cnwfg5

Contrary to what is said, I believe some protocols between monitor and graphics card can inform the DPI of the monitor, or the model and manufacturer of the monitor so that can be used to determine the DPI according to manufacturer specification. Thanks.

Comment: For applications that you dont want to rely on that infomation that can be wrong, you can simple present the user a graphics and ask it to measure the real size of it so you know for sure the DPI, the precision anyway depends on the user measurament.